# Fantasy novel about a world with mechanical dragons

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a short fantasy novel that centers around a young man who meets an older man who knows how their "Edwardian" world really works. The fantastic creatures, which haunt the world at night, are actually machines, built underground and recharged each day. The world was an extremely dangerous one at night, and the older man possessed a cart which was drawn by horses, I think, but which could be self propelled if he needed to escape the monsters.

At the end of the novel, a female journalist meets the two guys and threatens to write a story revealing the existence of the world to the rest of the galaxy. There is a really good scene involving combat with a half-finished mechanical dragon.

I cannot remember the title or author. It was a book from a thrift store which I read at least ten years ago. I am pretty sure the cover had been removed.

Comment: When did you read it? Remember any of the cover art? Any other details?

Comment: It was a book from a thrift store which I read at least ten years ago. I am pretty sure the cover had been removed, The world was an extremely dangerous one at night, and the older man possessed a cart which was drawn by horses, I think, but which could be self propelled if he needed to escape the monsters.......

Comment: Alas, these are not the book. But! They do look pretty cool, and have some of the same themes. I will definitely give them a try......

Comment: Could it be [The Steerswoman](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheSteerswoman) series?

Comment: No, but good suggestion. This series has some of the same themes.....

Comment: I believe this is the same book I am looking for. I vaguely recall it being "Night" something or other but can't find anything that matches. Any luck for you?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds similar to [The Dragons of Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dragons_of_Babel) by Michael Swanwick, which is set in the same world as his earlier novel [The Iron Dragon's Daughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Dragon%27s_Daughter). Points of similarity:

- Main character is male, and has interactions with other, older characters who help him discover many things about the world
- much of the first part of the novel involves repairing and recharging the a dragon
- Dragons are mechanical, being built as weapons of war, and are sentient/sapient
- There are scenes where the main dragon (and others) are involved in combat

Comment: I will check these out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Alas, these are not the book. But! They do look pretty cool. They definitely share some of the same themes and I will try reading them......